# inconsistent day calculations from php

Tags: php, date, datetime, timezone, days

This script returns inconsistent days count.
At localhost returns 14 days on the clients server returns 15 days.

```
    $_POST['pickup_time'] = '13:30';
    $_POST['dropoff_time'] = '12:00';
    $_POST['pickup_date'] = '2013-10-16';
    $_POST['dropoff_date'] = '2013-10-30';


    $fmt_pickup_date = strtotime($_POST['pickup_date']);
    $fmt_dropoff_date = strtotime($_POST['dropoff_date']);

    $days = ceil(abs($fmt_dropoff_date - $fmt_pickup_date) / 86400);

    if ($vehicles[$v]['vehicle_cal_date']==0)
    {
        $fmt_pickup_time = str_replace(":", "", $_POST['pickup_time']);
        $fmt_dropoff_time = str_replace(":", "", $_POST['dropoff_time']);

        if (($fmt_dropoff_time-$fmt_pickup_time)>=1)
        {
            $days++;
        }
    }
    else { $days++; }
```

For some dates returns right days count and for some wrong (+1 day).

```
    [pickup_time] => 11:00
    [dropoff_time] => 10:00
    [pickup_date] => 2013-10-28
    [dropoff_date] => 2013-11-01
```

These dates returns on both servers 4 days wich is right.

Any ideas? What is wrong?

Edit:

It seems that this:

```
    date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
```

fixes the problem and now the script returns correct days count for both dates. For how long - no idea. I hope that this will fix it for all the dates :)

Comment: At what timezone the servers you're using are configured? Maybe they have different dates.

Comment: You really should NOT be doing 'math' on strings. `13:30` - `12:00` may work, but it's still highly hinky even with the `:` => empty string replacements you're doing.  Why not use the provided php DateTime class to do all this 'math'?

Comment: Any differences in the 'vehicle_cal_date' variable? As this could cause the days++?

Comment: Please ka-spot read my suggestion, try always to use php built in function before writing your own code

Answer (score 2):

The issue is really simple, and it's the one I've been repeating around for a long time... And of course it works if you set the timezone to UTC!

Why?

Simply, because of DST. When DST starts or ends, days are not long 24 hours (but 23 or 25 instead). So, when you do the math with 86400 seconds, which are 24 hours, that does not work!

Setting the timezone to UTC, which does not use DST, is a workaround. However, in my opinion the cleanest solution would be to use the DateTime class and let it do the math: http://php.net/datetime
Those functions have builtin support for timezones, so they handle DST correctly.

Comment: @notneededanymore This answer literally answers your question brilliantly.  Please award it the green tick.  sandino, in case you haven't already, should receive an upvote from you because he has supplied the shortest possible solution for your case.

Answer (score 1):

This may have something to do with the differences in the php setup on localhost vs. the client's server.  What I have done in the past is compared the phpinfo() for each to see where the issue could be.  Maybe the date configuration for php?

Comment: This answer isn't necessarily wrong but is more of a generalized guess when compared to Qualcuno's dead-on answer.  This answer could almost be a comment on the question.

Comment: Agreed @mickmackusa. I was still a noob when I posted this as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use your own code to make things that php already does.

Try this:

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2013-10-28');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2013-11-01');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
```

That output is +4 days.

Hope this helps you

Here is the official documentation about datetime functions and all you can do it with them:
http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php